# Can't copy full value of a text to console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to paste some values but only parts of it appears in the console app screen, using c# and console app. I am trying to copy the values below, but when I paste it, only the first row appears. I don't know why it doesn't paste right. I need the full value of the text so i can use it in a variable via Console.Readline(), but I can't seem to get it, does anyone have an idea of why this happens?

in code it is just:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

But **when i paste something during the readline it only pastes the first row**. I believe it is not wrong in the code, rather the copying to the console application.

[The text im trying to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOt0C.png)

```
> 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
> 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0
> 1.0 1.0 20.0 20.0 10.0 0
```

This is the result at the moment:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuexS.png)

Comment: The new lines are handled as, well, new lines by ReadLine(). You could put the ReadLine in a loop, and break when, say, am empty line is encountered?

Comment: The thing is, the whole value is not read in the input. The rest of values is gone, it doesn't exist in the program due to it was never read. It has to appear in the console app screen, you should see the whole value i believe....

Comment: @Lucy Check the posted answer it must help.

Comment: @rad It is not really the problem in this case, it is when you copy the values in the input.

Answer (score 2):

`Console.ReadLine()` reads only one line and the end of each line is specified by `Enter Key`.
Your text contains `Enter Char` at the end of each line, so after reaching the first `enter char` which is at the end of the first line the program passes the `Console.ReadLine()`.
However, you can use a loop to read multiple lines.
Sample code:

```
    string line;
    string text = "";
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "")
    {
        text += line + "\n";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.Read();
```

In this sample code, after pressing Enter on an empty line the text reading is done.

Comment: It did not solve my problem, it would just rewrite the uncomplete input... the problem is just pasting the value. When pasting it is uncomplete in the console app, but in notepad/somewhere else the full value is there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with another walk around instead. Instead of reading everything in one big value I just read five at a time.